# Vector Mapping for iOS?

Tags: openstreetmap, vector, ios, tilestache, mapbox

Are there any vector map data providers with API's, that i can use to build my app on iOS natively (not on a webview). Specifically im looking for:

1. For a library/framework that uses existing map servers as datasources to get  vector maps. Even a HTTP based API that returns vector map data would be helpful!
2. Any tools that would help me render (on openGL) such a map on iOS. Mapnik (http://mapnik.org/) looks good, but im still unsure on how i would go about using it!

Things I've looked and why those wont work for me (tell me otherwise!):

1. Google Maps & Apple Maps : Cannot use as a datasource for vector map format.
2. Mapbox : Coming out with map vector support. Not yet out there.
3. TileStache : Looks promising. Would like more information on this if anyone has used it?

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing [MapBox iOS SDK](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/) that pulls raster tiles rather than vector tiles, but is native. It can bring in other vector sources for overlays, like GeoJSON and KML, if necessary.

TileStache is a Python map server, not a Obj-C map client.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but there are some new answers now.
WhirlyGlobe-Maply can now do vector map display on iOS.  http://mousebirdconsulting.blogspot.com/2014/03/vector-maps-introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Try MapBox-gl, it's in preview phase and has full vector support written in C++ and OpenGL ES.